# Winds or waves in specific conditions?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, atmospheric-science, planets, exoplanets

Winds are mainly produced by differences in temperature of the atmosphere and waves are mainly produced by winds.

However, could a rogue planet (without orbiting any star and with a cold core so no influence of these factors would exist, but that somehow has an atmosphere and big areas of liquid material, similar to our seas) have any winds or waves? I've learnt that there are wind currents and waves produced only by our planet's rotation, with no other source or influence (see the answer to [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24250/are-there-any-types-of-winds-or-waves-that-are-produced-just-by-earths-rotation)), so preumably the rogue planet would also have winds and waves of some form, right?

And also, I've read sometimes that the Moon's tidal forces can cause some winds. If the rogue planet (again, with no star and a cold core) had a moon and they got tidally locked, could there be any winds? (Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand that there wouldn't be any tides in the planet's oceans due to the tidal locking of both celestial bodies...However, would it be the same for winds in the rogue planet)?

Comment: Are you implying that your planet has no temperature gradients because of the absence of star and of a thermally active core? Do you mean it is 0K everwhere? How would that coincide with matter in liquid and gaseous form?

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Not necessarily 0K but at least with an uniform temperature so no differences of temperature could create wind currents. Anyways this is purely a theoretical mental experiment that's why I said that this planet has somehow an atmosphere and big areas of liquid material